# Why can't I do console.log in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script.
As shown when you run the snippet, `console.log` doesn't work. 
How can I enable it?

```js
datain = {
        "threshold": 1.5,
        "sample_response_score": 0.439,
        //"celltype_response_thres": 0.064,
        "celltype_response_thres": 'foo',
        "histograms": [
            {
                "sample": "Sample1",
                "nof_genes": 26,
                "values": [
                    {
                        "score": 0.042924727328924939,
                        "celltype": "Bcells"
                    },
                    {
                        "score": 0.073045907156188195,
                        "celltype": "DendriticCells"
                    }]
                  
                }]}
   
           



jQuery(function ($) {
     $.get(datain, function (data) {
         console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
       
       });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: check your developer tools console and network tab for errors

Comment: I suggest you read the manual for [`$.get`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/). You seem to think it does something else

Comment: what happens in $.get without a URL?

Comment: @JaromandaX you end up with *"XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://stacksnippets.net/[object%20Object]`."*

Comment: what I meant was, what URL does $.get try without an url present :p - oh, yeah, you answered that :p

Comment: @JaromandaX looks to me like it goes something like `url = arguments[0].url || arguments[0].toString()` (or there abouts)

Comment: there was a change in this behaviour 1.12 and 2.2 - prior to this, it doesn't check for url property on argument 0

Answer (score 4):

console.log is working fine-- you're just using `.get` incorrectly, so the callback is never firing.  See my snippet.

See the documentation for [`jQuery.get`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) -- it is expecting a URL to fetch data, or a configuration object with a `url` property.  You seem to be attempting to just pass it the result object you want to be fetching.  (Thanks Phil for the correction)

```js
console.log('it works fine');
datain = {
        "threshold": 1.5,
        "sample_response_score": 0.439,
        //"celltype_response_thres": 0.064,
        "celltype_response_thres": 'foo',
        "histograms": [
            {
                "sample": "Sample1",
                "nof_genes": 26,
                "values": [
                    {
                        "score": 0.042924727328924939,
                        "celltype": "Bcells"
                    },
                    {
                        "score": 0.073045907156188195,
                        "celltype": "DendriticCells"
                    }]
                  
                }]}
   
           



jQuery(function ($) {
     $.get(datain, function (data) {
         console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
       
       });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: FYI, `$.get` can accept an object but it expects it to have an `url` property. See https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/#jQuery-get-settings

Comment: @Phil -- fixed-- thanks!

Comment: @Phil only as of v 1.12/2.2 - so 2.1.1 wont do that

Comment: @JaromandaX how does that `1.12/2.2` thing work? Did they remove it at some time then add it back?

Comment: He is right. You are a bit confused on SETTINGS, the object you are passing as datain is not a valid SETTINGS for $.get. Where should $.get() be pointing to fetch the data? Nowhere. So your callback never runs.

Comment: parallel development of 1.x and 2.x - so, 2.2 was around the same time as 1.12 ... no backporting into 2.1 of the changes made in 2.2 ... damn confusing with 3 major lines of jquery!!!

Answer (score 0):

`get` :  Load data from the server using a HTTP GET request

**Example:**

```
$.get( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

```js
datain = {
        "threshold": 1.5,
        "sample_response_score": 0.439,
        //"celltype_response_thres": 0.064,
        "celltype_response_thres": 'foo',
        "histograms": [
            {
                "sample": "Sample1",
                "nof_genes": 26,
                "values": [
                    {
                        "score": 0.042924727328924939,
                        "celltype": "Bcells"
                    },
                    {
                        "score": 0.073045907156188195,
                        "celltype": "DendriticCells"
                    }]
                  
                }]}
   
           



//jQuery(function ($) {
//    $.get(datain, function (data) {
         console.log(JSON.stringify(datain));
       
//       });
//  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Maybe you are not loading data from server properly using `get`.

You can also use `ajax` method for the same.

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

*ajax reference*: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp